# Nuxt.js app error when starting on Azure web apps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, nuxt.js

I'm trying to run a Nuxt.js application on Azure. When I deploy the application (successfully) using Azure Devops CI/CD to Azure web apps, the application won't run.

See the error below.

As far as I understand this means that the package.json can't be found and because of that the application can't start.

Images of my build/release pipeline on Azure Devops [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBS6D.jpg).

```
2019-09-11T08:09:27.409935226Z   _____                               
2019-09-11T08:09:27.409972726Z   /  _  \ __________ _________   ____  
2019-09-11T08:09:27.409980026Z  /  /_\  \___   /  |  \_  __ \_/ __ \ 
2019-09-11T08:09:27.409985426Z /    |    \/    /|  |  /|  | \/\  ___/ 
2019-09-11T08:09:27.409990326Z \____|__  /_____ \____/ |__|    \___  >
2019-09-11T08:09:27.409995626Z         \/      \/                  \/ 
2019-09-11T08:09:27.410000626Z A P P   S E R V I C E   O N   L I N U X
2019-09-11T08:09:27.410005526Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:27.410009926Z Documentation: http://aka.ms/webapp-linux
2019-09-11T08:09:27.410014626Z NodeJS quickstart: https://aka.ms/node-qs
2019-09-11T08:09:27.410019226Z NodeJS Version : v10.16.0
2019-09-11T08:09:27.410023826Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:27.781011935Z /opt/startup/init_container.sh: line 32: [: ==: unary operator expected
2019-09-11T08:09:28.029460609Z Oryx Version : 0.2.20190730.1, Commit: 4ef0d5854df39c57605e59bb6d255215cc85468a
2019-09-11T08:09:28.067056450Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:28.093996380Z Cound not find build manifest file at '/home/site/wwwroot/oryx-manifest.toml'
2019-09-11T08:09:28.094015980Z Could not find operation ID in manifest. Generating an operation id...
2019-09-11T08:09:28.094229780Z Build Operation ID: 3b273fa4-2c0a-44fe-82d5-d3558b0f435e
2019-09-11T08:09:28.981601858Z Writing output script to '/opt/startup/startup.sh'
2019-09-11T08:09:28.992611670Z Running #!/bin/sh
2019-09-11T08:09:28.993286971Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:28.993302171Z # Enter the source directory to make sure the script runs where the user expects
2019-09-11T08:09:28.993319471Z cd "/home/site/wwwroot"
2019-09-11T08:09:28.993325871Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:28.994364772Z if [ -z "$PORT" ]; then
2019-09-11T08:09:28.994378572Z      export PORT=8080
2019-09-11T08:09:28.994997373Z fi
2019-09-11T08:09:28.995010873Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:28.995015273Z PATH="$PATH:/home/site/wwwroot" npm run start:prod
2019-09-11T08:09:31.501668636Z npm ERR! path /home/site/wwwroot/package.json
2019-09-11T08:09:31.502666537Z npm ERR! code ENOENT
2019-09-11T08:09:31.518772254Z npm ERR! errno -2
2019-09-11T08:09:31.518809454Z npm ERR! syscall open
2019-09-11T08:09:31.520098056Z npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/site/wwwroot/package.json'
2019-09-11T08:09:31.521179157Z npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2019-09-11T08:09:31.522101458Z npm ERR! enoent 
2019-09-11T08:09:31.640775689Z 
2019-09-11T08:09:31.641914090Z npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-09-11T08:09:31.646957596Z npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-09-11T08_09_31_532Z-debug.log
```

However when I check the index of wwwroot I can see that my application is not there. Only an "S" directory which DOES contains the application. How do those files get in this "S" directory?

How do I get them out or change the working directory so the script won't fail?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Can you share your Azure Pipeline? probably something in the deploy step.

Comment: It seems there is something wrong in your deployment, could you please share some more steps of your deployment ?

Comment: See [this link](https://imgur.com/a/HCPPEq1) for more information about my build/release pipeline

Comment: @janekkkk Did you tried below solution? How did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you might accidently checking option **`Prepend root folder name to archive paths`** in the **archive files** task in your build pipeline. Checking this option will end up getting your files in **"S"** folder.

[image]

Please check task `Achive Files` of your build pipeline, Make sure `Prepend root folder name to archive paths` is unchecked.